# How can I automate the publishing of an Android app to Play Store with Fastlane when I create a new Release on GitHub?

Tags: android, github, google-play, publishing, fastlane

I'm developing an open source app that is on a public GitHub repository (https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger) and, when an update is ready, I usually merge the develop branch into master branch and I add a new Release to the repository.
The repo already have the fastlane folder tree with screenshots, changelogs, descriptions and icon.

There is a way to automate the publishing of the new app update on Google Play Console using Fastlane?

I would like to trigger that automation when I create the new release on GitHub, and I would like to use the apk I attached to the release.

I already know the play console part (create a service account and download the .json file, is well described [here](https://medium.com/scalereal/automate-publishing-app-to-the-google-play-store-with-github-actions-fastlane-ac9104712486)), but I don't know how to trigger the publishing on GitHub, for example using GitHub actions.